# Room entity with multiple list parameters

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have model like this:

```
data class TotalBalance(
    val totalBalance: String,
    val cryptoBalance: GroupBalance,
    val fiatBalance: GroupBalance,
    val savingsBalance: GroupBalance,
    val cardsBalance: GroupBalance,
)

data class GroupBalance(
    val total: String,
    val balance: List<Balance>,
)

data class Balance(
    val id: String = "",
    val asset: String = "",
    val balance: String = "",
    val refBalance: String = "",
)
```

How to store it in Room? I understand that I need to use the ForeignKey and @Relation but how?

---

**UPD**

I need to store 4 list of balances objects for each group.

Each of these lists can contain a large number of items so I don't want to merge them all into one list.

I will also need to save all objects, get all saved balances, get saved balances for a certain group, for example, crypto or fiat, and also get a balance object only for a certain "asset" (field in the BalanceRoom)

I through about Entity like this:

```
data class TotalBalanceRoom(
    val totalBalance: String,
    val totalCrypto: String,
    val totalFiat: String,
    val totalSavings: String,
    val totalCards: String,
    val cryptoBalances: List<BalanceRoom>,
    val fiatBalances: List<BalanceRoom>,
    val savingsBalances: List<BalanceRoom>,
    val cardsBalances: List<BalanceRoom>,
)
```

But how to store few lists in one entity?

If that's not possible or too complicated I'm thinking of splitting this model into two separate ones. One of them will contain all strings with a total balances, and the others will store all balances objects, each of which will also contain additional type: crypto, fiat, saving or card

Comment: I posted an answer below to show how to get a list of `Balance` objects using a single entity and dao. On a side note, why are you storing numeric data as a string? This makes it difficult to do mathematical calculations, such as summing a total.

Comment: I need to use string according to our business logic. Imagine that this is not total balance but wallet id for example. It's not possible to calculate this on the client side

Comment: Then you should name it "wallet id" instead of "total balance".

Comment: In fact, this is totalBalance, I suggested simply imagining that this is any other string so that they no longer offer to take data not from the backend, but to count it locally. I just don't understand why, instead of answering my question, I am offered to change the business logic and calculate the total balance on the client after I said that this is not possible. The point is not at all what exactly this string is, the task is to store an entity with several lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after reading all those irrelevant answers above that just suggested that I change the system logic and read the balance value on the client instead of using the server as the only source of truth, I solved this problem in a slightly different way.

I merged all the balance options into one list, adding each entity type: saving, fiat, crypto or card.

After that, I used the standard one-to-many approach. So my mods now look like this:

```
data class UserBalanceRoom(
    @Embedded val totalBalance: TotalBalanceRoom = TotalBalanceRoom(),
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "refCurrencyShortCode",
        entity = BalanceRoom::class,
        entityColumn = "refCurrency"
    )
    var balances: List<BalanceRoom> = emptyList(),
)

@Entity(tableName = TotalBalanceRoom.Companion.TABLE_NAME)
data class TotalBalanceRoom(
    @PrimaryKey
    val refCurrencyShortCode: String = "",
    val totalBalance: String = "",
    val cryptoTotal: String = "",
    val fiatTotal: String = "",
    val savingTotal: String = "",
    val cardsTotal: String = "",
) {
    object Companion {
        const val TABLE_NAME = "total_balance"
    }
}

@Entity(
    tableName = BalanceRoom.Companion.TABLE_NAME,
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = TotalBalanceRoom::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("refCurrencyShortCode"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("refCurrency"),
            onUpdate = CASCADE,
            onDelete = CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class BalanceRoom(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: String = "",
    val asset: String = "",
    val balance: String = "",
    val refBalance: String = "",
    val type: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    val refCurrency: String = "",
) {
    object Companion {
        const val TABLE_NAME = "balance"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without example data and what you intend to relate to what, the model could be interpreted in many ways, as such a definitive answer can't really be given.

- *Perhaps you may wish to edit your question to clarify by including some example data and defining the relationships.*

**However**, it would appear that you could perhaps retrieve all the information you require by simply having a single table for the balances *(possibly just transactions assuming some form of accounting)*. As such  relationships, at least in respect to balances may not be required.

Perhaps consider the following demonstration based solely on the **Balance**s being stored. That is a single **Balance** table and thus only the **Balance** class being annotated with `@Entity`, as per:-

```
@Entity
data class Balance(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: String = "",
    val asset: String = "",
    val balance: String = "",
    val refBalance: String = "",
)
```

- i.e. `@Entity` annotation added, and
- the required `@PrimaryKey` annotation being applied to a column.

Second, a POJO for retrieving the various balances based upon your TotalBalance class:-

```
data class TotalBalance(
    val totalBalance: String,
    val cryptoBalance: /*GroupBalance*/ String,
    val fiatBalance: /*GroupBalance*/ String,
    val savingsBalance: /*GroupBalance*/ String,
    val cardsBalance: /*GroupBalance*/ String,
)
```

- GroupBalance simply not being required, so a String (as you are using Strings) instead.

  - Saying that `getBalanceForAnAsset` as below may reflect a  GroupBalance.

Obviously to use the above functions to access the database (store and retrieve data) are required. You want to be able to retrieve a TotalBalance object (and perhaps a balance per a group (*noting that it is assumed that **asset** is akin to a group*, this suiting the demo)). So in an `@Dao` annotated interface that has been called **AllDAOs**:-

```
@Dao
interface AllDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(balance: Balance): Long
    @Query("SELECT sum(coalesce(CAST(balance AS REAL),0.0)) FROM balance WHERE asset=:asset")
    fun getBalanceForAnAsset(asset: String): Double

    @Query("SELECT " +
            "(SELECT sum(coalesce(CAST(balance AS REAL),0.0)) FROM balance) AS totalBalance," +
            "(SELECT sum(coalesce(CAST(balance AS REAL),0.0)) FROM balance WHERE asset='crypto') AS cryptoBalance," +
            "(SELECT sum(coalesce(CAST(balance AS REAL),0.0)) FROM balance WHERE asset='fiat') AS fiatBalance, +" +
            "(SELECT sum(coalesce(CAST(balance AS REAL),0.0)) FROM balance WHERE asset='savings') AS savingsBalance," +
            "(SELECT sum(coalesce(CAST(balance AS REAL),0.0)) FROM balance WHERE asset='cards') AS cardsBalance")
    fun getTotalBalanceObject(): TotalBalance
}
```

- Note that this is not intended to provide the most efficient queries, but instead it provides relatively easy to understand queries.
- the SQLite `coalesce` function has been used as a String value may not equate to a numeric value, in which case the numeric value of 0.0 would be used.
- the SQLite `sum` aggregate function adds the values of a group, the default group (i.e. in the absence of a GROUP BY clause) being ALL output rows.

With a simple `@Database` annotated abstract class incorporating a singleton approach for retrieving an instance of the class, as per:-

```
@Database(entities = [Balance::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAOs(): AllDAOs
    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance=Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

- Note that this is intended ONLY FOR DEMONSTRATION PUPOSES and thus allows the main thread to be used for brevity and convenience of the answer.

Now some Activity code to actually demonstrate both storing and retrieving data:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAOs()
        val typeCrypto = "crypto"
        val typeFiat = "fiat"
        val typeSavings = "savings"
        val typeCards = "cards"

        /* Load data for the various types (assets) 3 rows per type all using the same value */
        dao.insert(Balance(System.currentTimeMillis().toString(),typeCrypto,"100.00","?"))
        dao.insert(Balance(System.currentTimeMillis().toString(),typeFiat,"101.00","?"))
        dao.insert(Balance(System.currentTimeMillis().toString(),typeSavings,"102.00","?"))
        dao.insert(Balance(System.currentTimeMillis().toString(),typeCards,"103.00","?"))
        dao.insert(Balance(System.currentTimeMillis().toString(),typeCrypto,"100.00","?"))
        dao.insert(Balance(System.currentTimeMillis().toString(),typeFiat,"101.00","?"))
        dao.insert(Balance(System.currentTimeMillis().toString(),typeSavings,"102.00","?"))
        dao.insert(Balance(System.currentTimeMillis().toString(),typeCards,"103.00","?"))
        dao.insert(Balance(System.currentTimeMillis().toString(),typeCrypto,"100.00","?"))
        dao.insert(Balance(System.currentTimeMillis().toString(),typeFiat,"101.00","?"))
        dao.insert(Balance(System.currentTimeMillis().toString(),typeSavings,"102.00","?"))
        dao.insert(Balance(System.currentTimeMillis().toString(),typeCards,"103.00","?"))

        /* extract the data first via the TotalBalances POJO 
            and then individually per asset (noting that Totals has not been catered for)
         */
        val allBalanaces = dao.getTotalBalanceObject()
        Log.d("RESULTS1","Crypto = ${allBalanaces.cryptoBalance} Fiat = ${allBalanaces.fiatBalance} Savings = ${allBalanaces.savingsBalance} Cards = ${allBalanaces.cardsBalance} TOTAL = ${allBalanaces.totalBalance}")
        Log.d( "RESULTS2","Crypto = ${dao.getBalanceForAnAsset(typeCrypto)} Fiat = ${dao.getBalanceForAnAsset(typeFiat)} Savings = ${dao.getBalanceForAnAsset(typeSavings)} Cards = ${dao.getBalanceForAnAsset(typeCards)}")
    }
}
```

**Result of the Demo**

2 lines are output, they are:-

```
2023-09-05 10:02:16.109 D/RESULTS1: Crypto = 300 Fiat = 303 Savings = 306 Cards = 309 TOTAL = 1218
2023-09-05 10:02:16.115 D/RESULTS2: Crypto = 300.0 Fiat = 303.0 Savings = 306.0 Cards = 309.0
```

- The values returned are as expected
- The 2nd line is less the total (which could be calculated from the 4 returned values).

> Unfortunately, I can't use the approach you suggested, since I need to use strings that come from the server to ensure maximum precision.

Well you could, as the precision afforded by a REAL type is probably far in excess of what is really needed. However, this point will be ignored.

So assuming that you insist on storing a List of Strings, then all that you can do (albeit inadvisable, as will be discussed). Room aka SQLite (Room is just a wrapper around SQLite), can only store a limited number of types of values, none of them a List/Array of Objects.

As such the List has to be stored as a representation of the List. Now Room can stores values as TEXT (a single String), INTEGER (a 64bit signed integer value), a REAL (8 Byte IEEE floating point number) or a BLOB (bytestream / ByteArray). So the List has to be converted into one of these. Typically a JSON representation of the List as a String aka TEXT.

However there are a number of JSON/GSON libraries available. So what you are looking for (again albeit it inadvisable) is a TypeConverter that will convert the List into a String that represents the List.

- inadvisable as:-

  - there are limitations as to how long the String can be,
  - JSON wraps each element with a descriptive via delimiters around the values further increasing the length of the data stored.
  - accessing the underlying data can complex and often restricts what can be achieved through queries, thus often it is necessary to extract the data into the objects to then process the data.

Again irrespective of the cautions. Perhaps consider the following demo.

The **BalanceRoom** class (assumed to be the same as the Balance Class):-

```
data class BalanceRoom(
    val id: String = "",
    val asset: String = "",
    val balance: String = "",
    val refBalance: String = ""
)
```

For the simplicity of using the com.google.code.gson library (Maven) for TypeConversion a class, **BalanceRoomList** that simplifies the conversion:-

```
data class BalanceRoomList(
    val brl: List<BalanceRoom>
)
```

A modified **TotalBalanceRoom** to

1. be an `@Entity` (annotated and primary key added so it can be a Room table)
2. To incorporate the **BalanceRoomList**

as per:-

```
@Entity
data class TotalBalanceRoom(
    /* Primary key added as one is required
        note a primary key has to be a unique (may be that no single column is unique hence simple id added)
     */
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?=null,
    val totalBalance: String,
    val totalCrypto: String,
    val totalFiat: String,
    val totalSavings: String,
    val totalCards: String,
    /* Note change to use BalanceRoomList object to suit simple use of com.google.code.gson library */
    val cryptoBalances: BalanceRoomList,
    val fiatBalances: BalanceRoomList,
    val savingsBalances: BalanceRoomList,
    val cardsBalances: BalanceRoomList,
)
```

A class **MyRoomTypeConverters** with TypeConverter functions, noting that per a type that needs conversion 2 functions are required 1) to convert to store the data and one to convert when extracting the data:-

```
class MyRoomTypeConverters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromBalanceRoomListToJSONString(balanceRoomList: BalanceRoomList): String = Gson().toJson(balanceRoomList)
    @TypeConverter
    fun toBalanceRoomListFromJSONString(jsonString: String): BalanceRoomList = Gson().fromJson(jsonString,BalanceRoomList::class.java)
}
```

- **NOTE** the singular `@TypeConverter` annotations **NOT `@TypeConverters`** (as used later).

Now Room has to know about where to find the TypeConverters, so  the `@TypeConverters` (***PLURAL***) annotation is required. For simplicity the fullest/greatest scope is at the `@Database` level (see later).

Obviously there will be a need to be able to add and extract data so an `@Dao` annotated class **TheDAOs**:-

```
@Dao
interface TheDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(totalBalanceRoom: TotalBalanceRoom): Long
    @Query("SELECT * FROM totalbalanceroom")
    fun getAllTotalBalanceRooms(): List<TotalBalanceRoom>
}
```

Putting all of the Room code together an `@Database` annotated class **ThisDatabase**. Noting the inclusion of the `@TypeConverters` (***PLURAL***) annotation:-

```
@Database(entities = [TotalBalanceRoom::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(value = [MyRoomTypeConverters::class])
abstract class ThisDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getTheDAOs(): TheDAOs
    companion object {
        private var instance: ThisDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): ThisDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance=Room.databaseBuilder(context,ThisDatabase::class.java,"this.database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as ThisDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

To actually demonstrate, some activity code to insert a single row and to then extract the data from that row:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: ThisDatabase
    lateinit var dao: TheDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = ThisDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getTheDAOs()

        val brl1 = BalanceRoomList(
            listOf(
                BalanceRoom("10","asset01","#500.1234567890123456789","ref????"),
                BalanceRoom("11","asset02","#501.1234567890123456789","ref????"),
                BalanceRoom("12","asset03","#502.1234567890123456789","ref????")
            )
        )
        val brl2 = BalanceRoomList(
            listOf(
                BalanceRoom("20","asset01","#600.1234567890123456789","ref????"),
            )
        )
        val brl3 = BalanceRoomList(
            listOf()
        )
        val brl4 = BalanceRoomList(
            listOf(
                BalanceRoom("40","asset05","#800.1234567890123456789","ref????"),
                )
        )
        /* Load a single TotalBalanceRoom row */
        val tbr = TotalBalanceRoom(
            null,
            "#1000.09876543210987654321",
            "#2000.09876543210987654321",
            "#3000.09876543210987654321",
            "#4000.09876543210987654321","#5000.09876543210987654321",
        brl1,brl2,brl3,brl4)
        /* Insert the row */
        dao.insert(tbr)

        /* Extract the data */
        for (tbr in dao.getAllTotalBalanceRooms()) {
            val sb_crpt = StringBuilder()
            for (crpt in tbr.cryptoBalances.brl) {
                sb_crpt.append("ID is ${crpt.id} ASSET is ${crpt.asset} BALANCE is ${crpt.balance} REF is ${crpt.refBalance}")
            }
            val sb_fiat = StringBuilder()
            for (fiat in tbr.fiatBalances.brl) {
                sb_fiat.append("ID is ${fiat.id} ASSET is ${fiat.asset} BALANCE is ${fiat.balance} REF is ${fiat.refBalance}")
            }
            val sb_sav = StringBuilder()
            for (sav in tbr.savingsBalances.brl) {
                sb_sav.append("ID is ${sav.id} ASSET is ${sav.asset} BALANCE is ${sav.balance} REF is ${sav.refBalance}")
            }
            val sb_card = StringBuilder()
            for (card in tbr.cardsBalances.brl) {
                sb_card.append("ID is ${card.id} ASSET is ${card.asset} BALANCE is ${card.balance} REF is ${card.refBalance}")
            }
            Log.d("DBINFO","TBR ID  is ${tbr.id} " +
                    "CRYPTOT is ${tbr.totalCrypto} " +
                    "FIATTOT = ${tbr.totalFiat} " +
                    "SAVTOT is ${tbr.totalSavings} " +
                    "CARDTOT is ${tbr.totalCards} " +
                    "TOTAL is ${tbr.totalBalance}." +
                    "\nThere are ${tbr.cryptoBalances.brl.size} Crypts; they are:-${sb_crpt}:" +
                    "\nThere are ${tbr.fiatBalances.brl.size} Fiats; They are:-${sb_fiat}:" +
                    "\nThere are ${tbr.savingsBalances.brl.size} Savs; They are:-${sb_sav}:" +
                    "\nThere are ${tbr.cardsBalances.brl.size} cards; They are:- ${sb_card}")
        }
    }
}
```

When run (for a fresh install) then the log includes:-

```
D/DBINFO: TBR ID  is 1 CRYPTOT is #2000.09876543210987654321 FIATTOT = #3000.09876543210987654321 SAVTOT is #4000.09876543210987654321 CARDTOT is #5000.09876543210987654321 TOTAL is #1000.09876543210987654321.
    There are 3 Crypts; they are:-ID is 10 ASSET is asset01 BALANCE is #500.1234567890123456789 REF is ref????ID is 11 ASSET is asset02 BALANCE is #501.1234567890123456789 REF is ref????ID is 12 ASSET is asset03 BALANCE is #502.1234567890123456789 REF is ref????:
    There are 1 Fiats; They are:-ID is 20 ASSET is asset01 BALANCE is #600.1234567890123456789 REF is ref????:
    There are 0 Savs; They are:-:
    There are 1 cards; They are:- ID is 40 ASSET is asset05 BALANCE is #800.1234567890123456789 REF is ref????
```

- as expected ***(noting that no attempt has been made to perform any calculations)** calculations would be complex to undertake*.

Now what may of of interest is what data is actually stored in the database; App Inspection shows, for example:-

[image]

- noting that the cryptoBalances column has been expanded to show that a fair amount of data has been stored *(at the expense of showing full data for any of the other columns)*.
- that data is just for 3 items al be it that the precision is rather large.
- The full content of the column is `{"brl":[{"asset":"asset01","balance":"#500.1234567890123456789","id":"10","refBalance":"ref????"},{"asset":"asset02","balance":"#501.1234567890123456789","id":"11","refBalance":"ref????"},{"asset":"asset03","balance":"#502.1234567890123456789","id":"12","refBalance":"ref????"}]}`

**Cautions**

As mentioned SQLite has  a limit on the length of a String as per:-

> Maximum length of a string or BLOB

> The maximum number of bytes in a string or BLOB in SQLite is defined by the preprocessor macro SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH. The default value of this macro is 1 billion (1 thousand million or 1,000,000,000). You can raise or lower this value at compile-time using a command-line option like this:

> -DSQLITE_MAX_LENGTH=123456789
> The current implementation will only support a string or BLOB length up to 231-1 or 2147483647. And some built-in functions such as hex() might fail well before that point. In security-sensitive applications it is best not to try to increase the maximum string and blob length. In fact, you might do well to lower the maximum string and blob length to something more in the range of a few million if that is possible.

> During part of SQLite's INSERT and SELECT processing, the complete content of each row in the database is encoded as a single BLOB. So the SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH parameter also determines the maximum number of bytes in a row.

> The maximum string or BLOB length can be lowered at run-time using the sqlite3_limit(db,SQLITE_LIMIT_LENGTH,size) interface.

**However**, The SQLite API utilises, which Room utilises, a buffer called a **Cursor** for retrieving data. A Cursor uses a finite memory allocation called a **Cursor Window**. A CursorWindow is limited up to 4Mb (may be more for Room as I think it overrides the size if need be). The Cursor Window MUST be able to hold at least 1 row. So if at 4Mb then 4,194,304 bytes. However, 1 row per CursorWindow will have a noticeable affect on performance if multiple rows have been extracted.

So in short taking the road of storing List could lead to issues. The database way would be to have an additional table for a list.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use the approach you suggested, since I need to use strings that come from the server to ensure maximum precision.